# Not the expected result while loading .mat file with scipy

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, scipy

I have the following problem while loading some data from a `.mat` file with scipy,

```
varI = variable_names
M = scipy.io.loadmat('path\file.mat', variable_names = varI)
```

What I get is,

```
{'__version__': '1.0', 'SensorI': array([[ 21809339.],
   [ 21809339.],
   [ 21809339.],
   ..., 
   [ 21809379.],
   [ 21809379.],
   [ 21809379.]]), '__header__': '', '__globals__': []}
```

But that isn't the whole data. The original variable is `SensorI 4013x1 32104  double'`. Do you have an idea why I don't get the whole data?

Comment: could you check the shape of the returned array? these previews very tricky for large arrays.

Comment: I did it. with, `M["SensorI"].shape` The result is, `(4013L, 1L)` Looks like the data is there. But how can I get it?

Comment: Just to clarify, `M["SensorI"]` does not contain all the expected data, right? The expected shape is `4013x1` or `4013x1x32104`?

Comment: In my view, `M["SensorI"]` contains the expected data. The ecpected shape is, `4013x1` like it obviously is. I'm able to get the data over a loop, `for i in range(len(M["SensorI"])):
    M["SensorI"][i]` 
That shows me all the values. But the goal is to get the whole array at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write "the goal is to get the whole array at once" --- the whole array is actually already there, `M["SensorI"]` gets it for you just fine. By "get" you seem to mean "print". Printing arrays just omits some elements by default, to avoid spewing thousands of lines to output.

What you apparently want is to adjust how arrays are displayed.
Use [numpy.set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)(edgeitems=numpy.inf) to always show all elements.

However, perhaps you were confused what "..." in the output mean --- it means there is data there, but wasn't just printed.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you all. The problem also existed in writing to csv file. That was a bit confusing.